# Continuar un consecutivo C#

Tags: c#

Como sumar 1 a mi numero de factura cuando pase por el metodo de imprimir y que continue donde quede al cerrar el programa, el label es LNumDoc

```
// Metodo para imprimir
    public void Print(Panel pnl)
    {
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        panel2 = pnl;
        getprintarea(pnl);
        prntprvw.Document = pntdoc;
        pntdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pntdoc_printpage);
        prntprvw.ShowDialog();
        // Cuando entre al metodo imprimir suma 1 al consecutivo
        // Y mantenga la cuenta donde quede al cerrar el programa
        LNumDoc.Text
    }
```

Comment: Donde recoges o registras el valor del consecutivo???

Comment: Es un Label que comienza en cero solo muestra el consecutivo de una factura por ejemplo factura N° - 103, no tiene relacion con nada

Comment: seria esto no  LNumDoc.Text = # ???

Comment: LNumDoc.Text = # , si puede ser LNumDoc.Text = (Numero en el que va) + 1 y mantenga donde va el consecutivo y le sume 1 cada vez que pase a imprimir

Comment: Okey estoy ya probando para ponerte la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno hasta donde he podido saber existen mas de una respuesta posible para lo que quieres hacer, aki te voy a dejar dos soluciones.

La primera es usando el Registro de Windows, en el cual podras guardar el contador y puedes consultarlo posteriormente.

En la clase de tu formulario principal creas un atributo protegido o privado:

```
//Variable donde se almacenara el contador que usas al imprimir
protected int contador;
```

Luego tienes que asignarle al evento `Load` y `FormClosed` de tu formulario principal los dos metodos que te voy a dejar a continuación:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //Con esto lees el valor almacenado en la clave HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\NOMBRE_DE_TU_APP\config
    contador = Convert.ToInt32(Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\"+Application.ProductName + "\\config").GetValue("contador", 1));
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //Con esto actualizas su valor, en caso de no existir la clave, la crea con el valor de contador actualizado
    Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(Application.ProductName + "\\config").SetValue("contador", this.contador+1);  
}
```

Con esto ya tienes una solucion. Si no has trabajado antes con el registro de windows o por razones de seguridad no quieres usarlo puedes guardar ese valor dentro de un xml. Aqui te dejo como lo harias, igual que en el anterior debes asignarle al formulario principal en los eventos `Load` y  `FormClosed` los metodos mostrados mas adelante.

Primero creariamos una clase llamada Configuracion para almacenar alli todos los datos que en un futuro podamos necesitar. Por si tu programa sigue evolucionando.

```
public class Configuracion
{
    //Constructor
    public Configuracion()
    {
        //Inicializo el contador en 1
        Contador = 1;
    }

    public int Contador;
}
```

Luego en la clase de tu Formulario principal añado estos atributos:

```
protected Configuracion config;
protected XmlSerializer serializer;
```

Recordar hacer uso de los using en este caso seria:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

El primero es porque voy a necesitar trabajar con directorios y con archivos y el segundo es para serializar mi clase dentro de un archivo xml que podre cargar posteriormente.

En el constructor del formulario tendria que poner lo siguiente:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Inicializo el atributo de donde voy a leer el contador
    config = new Configuracion();
    //Creo el atributo que voy a emplear para deserializar y serializar la clase Configuracion
    serializer = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApplication4.Configuracion"));
}
```

Debo dejar claro que si tu nombre de espacio es MiApp la ultima linea deberia ser

```
XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("MiApp.Configuracion"));
```

Es decir el nombre de espacio de la clase Configuracion

**Metodos**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    //Si existe el archivo config.xml dentro de la carpeta data en el directorio donde reside mi ejecutable... 
    if (File.Exists("data\\config.xml"))
    {
        //Abro el archivo para escribir en el la instancia de la clase Configuracion serializada
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("data\\config.xml"))
        {
            config = (Configuracion)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }                    
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //Si no existe el archivo config.xml dentro de la carpeta data en el directorio donde reside tu ejecutable...
    if (!File.Exists("data\\config.xml"))
    {
        //Crea la carpeta data
        Directory.CreateDirectory("data\\");
    }
    //Actualizo el contador almacenado en la instancia de la clase Configuracion que tengo como atributo de mi formulario
    config.Contador++;
    //Abro el archivo para escribir en el la clase serializada
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("data\\config.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, config);
    }                
}
```

Ahora en dependencia de cual de los 2 casos hayas usado tu metodo seria de la siguiente manera:

**CASO 1**:

```
LNumDoc.Text = contador.ToString();
```

**CASO 2**:

```
LNumDoc.Text = config.Contador.ToString();
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Cualquier duda ya sabes

Comment: Muchas gracias Dariel, estoy tratando de implementar el caso 1 pero me pone un 1113 y no queda guardado estoy poniendo 
    protected int contador;
arriba en el comienzo de la clase pincipal y
    LNumDoc.Text = contador.ToString();
dentro del metodo de imprimir

Comment: en el caso 2 dice Información adicional: DocEquivalente.Configuracion no es accesible por el nivel de protección. Sólo se pueden procesar tipos públicos.

Comment: Mira en tu anterior comentario el problema era que yo tenia **contador = Convert.ToInt32(Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\"+Application.ProductName + "\\config").GetValue("contador", 1113));** en vez de **contador = Convert.ToInt32(Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\"+Application.ProductName + "\\config").GetValue("contador", 1));**, es decir el valor por defecto lo tenia en 1113 pk estaba probando solo debes cambiarlo a 1, por cierto ya esta modificado en la respuesta

Comment: En tu segundo comentario te da error porque debes hacer publica la clase Configuracion yo la tenia en el mismo archivo que la del formulario solo debes verificar que en su declaración tenga **public class Configuracion**

Comment: ¿Y no es eso complicarse la existencia siendo que es más fácil y práctico guardar la información en una base de datos, o incluso en un archivo?

Comment: Y el registro de windows o el xml que cosa es???